# Images not appears on website after adding

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET Core project and want to add SVG icons to it

I added it under `wwwroot/images/MainSystem/Reports`

And I see it in the project and in explorer

After this, I wrote a css code to use them on background

Here is code

```
 .child.devices {
    background-image: url(../images/MainSystem/Reports-icons/Devices.svg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 150px;
}
```

And used like this in HTML

```
<div class="child devices"><span>Devices</span></div>
```

But image not appears. But I see it in style

[image]

I have no errors in the console

I tried clean project and rebuilt and clean cache.

Nothing happens. How I can fix this?

Comment: what happens if you visit `/images/MainSystem/Reports-icons/Devices.svg` in the browser?

Comment: To know if the link is correct : right-click on the link (developer console) , then select "Open in new tab", if the picture doesn't appear in a new tab then the link is wrong

Comment: I see this image@Alex

Comment: Try giving your `.child.devices` a width and height, like 500px, and see if you can see the background

Comment: try changing `background-size: 150px;` to `background-size: 150px 150px;`

Comment: Not see it anyway@Alex

Comment: I tried with image from different path and all okay. Maybe smth with svg? @Alex

Comment: Yeah, It's smth with icons @Alex

Comment: @EugeneSukh if you think its something with svg (maybe need the mime type in iis) then try a jpg and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me I have tried same way in my demo. I have just Removed ../ form path like images/MainSystem.... and then specify height and width to class and remove background size property.

see attached screenshot.

Thanks[image]